# Python list out of function

Tags: python, list, function, python-3.x, casting

I Need `['1', '2', '3']` to become this `[1, 2, 3]`

This is my actual code:

```
def chain_a_list_int(p_chain :str):
   tab_chain=[] # [str]
   tab_int=[] # [int] (list to return)

   tab_chain = p_chain.split(",")
   tab_chain = [int(i) for i in tab_chain]
   tab_int.append(tab_chain)
   return tab_int
```

and return it to use it like that:

```
chain_a_list_int(input("enter the number to conserve: "))
```

but it give me this error when i print it out of the function:

```
<function chain_a_list_int at 0x000000000349FEA0>
```

when i try to print i use this:

```
 print(chaine_a_liste_entier)
```

when i print `tab_int` **in the function** it work pretty well but it's not when i'm out of it...

```
print(tab_int)
```

Result...

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Or even `map(int, p_chain.split(','))`

Comment: That's not an error, but an indication that Python doesn't think that you have asked it to call `chain_a_list_int`.  Would you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39921730/edit) and add a bit more of the code you are using around what you've shown?  For example, please add the `print` statement you are using.

Comment: PS welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more on asking questions in a way that will attract quality answers.

Comment: @ForceBru how do i use this line?? (where should i put it)

Comment: @OlivierTurcotte, this is the solution. You could also do `map(int, input("enter the numbers, comma-separated: ").split(','))` _instead_ of all of your current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an error, but an indication that Python doesn't think that you have asked it to call `chain_a_list_int`.  The minimal tweak to your code is:

```
the_list = chain_a_list_int(input("enter the number to conserve: "))
print(the_list)
```

or

```
print(chain_a_list_int(input("enter the number to conserve: ")))
```

A reference to the name of the function `chain_a_list_int`, without a `(` after it, does not actually cause the function's code to run.  This distinction will be useful to you later on — for now, make sure any time you type the name of a function, you put a parenthesized expression after that name.  (If @ForceBru posts an answer, you'll see a counterexample :) .)

Comment: Can you please check part 2 of my probleme?

Comment: @OlivierTurcotte If you have two separate, unrelated problems, you are required to ask them as two separate questions. You should edit out anything from this question that's not relevant, and ask it as another one.

Comment: @OlivierTurcotte to follow up on what Random Davis said, asking a second question rather than editing an existing question makes it easier for future readers to benefit from the questions and answers.  Also, someone else may have a better answer to Part 2 than I would!  Asking a separate question for Part 2 makes it more likely that other folks will also be able to help.

Comment: @cxw alright, for the same question then, when i print the result it return me [[1,2,3]] so its not recognized as a int

Comment: @OlivierTurcotte Missed that one - instead of `tab_int.append(tab_chain)`, use `tab_int.extend(tab_chain)` per [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).  Or, better yet, just `return tab_chain` :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function to print its output, ie `print(chaine_a_liste_entier('1,3,5,6'))`.